# Как сохранить значение input в localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Есть `input` с `id=userName`, на нём же есть иконка с `id=remember_icon` по нажатию на которую я сохраняю значение `login` в `localStorage`, а потом при заходе на страницу проверяю, если `input` пустой, подставляю значение из хранилища, чтобы пользователь не вбивал каждый раз `login`, а только пароль, в `js` новичок, нагородил каши, а как в порядок привести не знаю). 
Заранее спасибо.

```
(function() {
  //инпут
  var inputLogin = document.getElementById("userName");
  //иконка по нажатию на которую сохранять логин
  var rememberIcon = document.getElementById("remember_icon");
  //переменная для сохранения
  var savedLogin;

  rememberIcon.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    inputLogin.value = localStorage.getItem('savedLogin') || '';
  });

  if (localStorage[inputLogin] && localStorage[inputLogin].length > 0) {
    inputLogin.val(localStorage[inputLogin]);
  }
})();
```

Comment: А вопрос то в чём?

Comment: @Darth дык не работает) и вообще нормальная реализация или нет

Comment: у инпутов нет метода `val`

Comment: keyup, надо слушать у inputLogin. Не? Либо на rememberIcon событие click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вряд ли Вам поможет, но все же:

```
var inputLogin; 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {            // при готовности объектной модели (когда все элементы документа созданы)
  inputLogin = document.getElementById('userName');              // выбираем из документа элемент инпута
  inputLogin.value = localStorage.getItem('savedLogin') || '';   // присваиваем его значению сохраненное в localStorage, либо пустую строку (при отсутствии сохр. знач.) 
  let rememberIcon = document.getElementById('remember_icon');   // выбираем элемент, который у нас будет реагировать на клик 
  rememberIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {                 // добавляем ему слушателя события "клик"... 
    localStorage.setItem('savedLogin', inputLogin.value);        // ...при котором, в localStorage будет добавлена/изменена запись с именем "savedLogin" и значением элемента inputLogin (на момент события)
  });
});
```

Comment: почему вряд ли? спасибо, возьму за основу, вопрос только почему в случае инпута использовался var, а в случае иконки let, есть какая-то разница?

Comment: @underwater, _«почему вряд ли?»_ - потому что, очевидно, Вы не стремитесь к знанию JS, так как возитесь с кодом без понимания основ (и это понимание никак не извлечь из готового кода). _«использовался var, а в случае иконки let, есть какая-то разница?»_ - да, есть разница в лексической области, и времени жизни переменной. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: я сейчас начал изучать js по learnjavascript с самых основ, но задачки лучше делать кучей малой самому и поправлять с помощью, чем не делать вообще.

Comment: @underwater, на самом деле, пока теория не усвоена - задачки лучше не делать вообще (иначе это прямая дорога в быдлокодинг). Уж поверьте: изучая последовательно - Вы достигнете гораздо большей эффективности.

Comment: _да, есть разница в лексической области_ - но в коде в ответе разница заметна не будет

Comment: @Grundy, конечно. Но если такой же код представить в "боевом" скрипте, разница будет заметна. К примеру, если далее используем переменную с тем же именем и забудем ее (там же) объявить-назначить, то в случае `let` при чтении будет брошено исключение - а в случае `var`, будет тихое и вероятно непредсказуемое поведение. Или `var`-переменные не выходят за область анонимной функции? (я так помню что выходят)

Comment: @yar85, тут опять все зависит от _боевого_ скрипта, в нем также может не быть разницы, а может быть

Comment: _Или var-переменные не выходят за область анонимной функции? (я так помню что выходят)_ - `var` ограничен функцией, не важно анонимная, неанонимная, стрелочная или еще какая.

Comment: @Grundy, точно. Я периодически путаю поведение `var`-переменных и неявно объявленных (т.к. и первое, и второе,  практически не использую) - сейчас как раз такой случай.

Answer (score 2):

Может быть всё дело в том,что вы слушаете не то событие? нужно же слушать `click`, а не нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре `keyup`
И не совсем поняла, почему подставляете потом в инпут такое значение `localStorage[inputLogin]`

Comment: не потом, а как раз вначале